# white space in joomla

Tags: templates, joomla, space

I can't figure out how to remove the white space between the opening paragraph in the middle of pages that contain multiple joomla elements (loading modules into article)  It's not a css issue and I don't see any issues in the template file either.  Can anyone offer any insight?

Here are a couple of affected pages:

http://www.myrtlebeachgolfmasters.com/bonus-points-form.html

http://www.myrtlebeachgolfmasters.com/forum/index.html

Comment: There are `clear:both` css settings on several of the elements in the form. This makes the element clear after any floated elements, which includes the sidebar that is floated to the right. You will likely either need to update the clear on the form pieces to not clear (`clear:none`) or change how the sidebar is built to not use a float in that way.

Comment: Thank you SO much, David! I never even though about the floats!

Comment: Awesome. I added my comment as an answer then so you can close out the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are `clear:both` css settings on several of the elements in the form. This makes the element clear after any floated elements, which includes the sidebar that is floated to the right. You will likely either need to update the clear on the form pieces to not clear (`clear:none`) or change how the sidebar is built to not use a float in that way.